# Enable all notifications permissions in Android

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

At least in my two xiaomi's phones when I install my app, it doesn't have all notifications permission (only vibrate, badge and lock screen) like in the pic.

[image]

What can I do to in my app to have all the notification permissions enabled by default?

Thanks!

Comment: did you found any method?

Comment: Hi @CarlosQuiroga, how can you enable the lock screen notification? My app didn't even enable it by default, can you show us the code?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from android 6.0 marshmallow you need to manually give permissions for security reasons. If the application isn't written in such way that it checks for permissions and asks for them, then you can't get them enabled by default(without going to settings).

Comment: So the only way is ask user to enabled all notifications options and send user to app settings, because there is not a way like in contacts, camera, location... etc (like this: https://developer.android.com/images/permissions/runtime_permission_request_2x.png)

Comment: Which Permission?

Comment: I don't think so. Messenger automatically has all options enabled. Messenger is a good example that can be done. I would also like to know how they do it

Comment: which permission by the way? is it ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY?

Answer (score -1):

You need to manually ask for permission for Android 6.0 and above. More informations : 
[Request App Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Comment: In Android, exists a notification permission? 

Which is? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission

Comment: The question is not about how to get the permissions.

Comment: Which permission need to add?

Comment: I don't think so. Messenger automatically has all options enabled. Messenger is a good example that can be done. I would also like to know how they do it. Remember that we are talking about permissions in the Notification